# enable disable jquery ui button with ajax

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm struggling to understand the options of enabling/disabling jquery ui buttons.

Typically in the past for any kind of button I've used:

```
jQuery(".mybutton").prop('disabled', false);
```

Depending on whether you want it enabled/disabled it would be false/true.

This seemed to work for jquery ui buttons as well. What I was doing was checking a certain count and disabling the button when you first load the page.

But someone could change the count value by deleting something (via AJAX call):

```
//delete 
jQuery(document).on("click", ".deletebutton", function() {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?"))
    {
        var hash = jQuery(this).data("delete");
        var $this = jQuery(this);
        jQuery.ajax({
           url: "index.php?option=com_cam&task=delete&hash="+ hash +"&"+getToken()+"=1&format=raw",
           dataType: 'json',
           type: "POST",
           success: function(data){
               if (data.type == 'error')
               {
                   //error message printed to user
               }
               else
               {
                   $this.closest("tr").remove();
                   //deleted so decrement and check if you have exceeded your limit

                   count=count-1;
                   if (count >= limit)  
                   {
                           //disable buttons
                           jQuery( ".mybutton" ).button( "option", "disabled", true );
                   }
                   else 
                   {
                       //enable add buttons and hide message
                       jQuery( ".mybutton" ).button( "option", "disabled", false );
                       //jQuery(".mybutton").attr('disabled', false);
                       //jQuery(".mybutton").prop('disabled', false);

                   }
               }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Then this should enable the button back again. Neither `prop` or `attr` or this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545248/jquery-ui-enabling-disabled-button-doesnt-restore-event)** seemed to work for me. Only when I did this:

```
jQuery( ".mybutton" ).button( "option", "disabled", false );
```

I guess I don't understand why `prop` doesn't work in this context when it does work to disable my buttons? Is the best practice to always use the button [setter](http://ui-dev.jquery.com/demos/button/#option-disabled)?

Comment: When using the button **widget**, you must disable the **widget** through the **widget's interface**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Under the hood, the button has been disabled, but, what you see is a button whose style has been set by jQuery UI.

jQuery UI does not set styles using disabled attribute (like `[disabled=disabled]`). Instead it adds two classes, to the button, which contain the disabled button styles: `ui-button-disabled`, `ui-state-disabled`.

There are four ways I know it will work.

1. **Recommended Way:** Call `jQuery('.mybutton').button('disable')`
2. **Your Way (also recommended):** Call `jQuery( ".mybutton" ).button( "option", "disabled", true );`
3. **This is fine:** Call `jQuery(".mybutton").prop('disabled', true).button('refresh')`. This refreshes the button UI.
4. **The not recommended way:** Add / remove the classes directly from the button. `jQuery(".mybutton").addClass('ui-button-disabled ui-state-disabled');`

Hope this explains to you why it works this way.

Answer (score 2):

You're no longer using the plain-jane `<button>` element, so changing the attributes isn't going to have much effect. jQuery-UI wraps the entire DOM element with helpers, separated events, and other details making the option accessor required.

So long as you're using [`.button`](http://api.jqueryui.com/button/), stick with the API and use the [disabled](http://api.jqueryui.com/button/#option-disabled) setting. (This holds true for any of the various widgets--datepicker, slider, etc.). Just think of the original DOM element as a standards placeholder that's only used to retain functionality with forms, but no longer the primary UI element.